# How to properly import a class definition from a module in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use the [AsyncAPI Generator](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator) in my typescript application. The generator is a commonjs module which is giving me some grief.

```js
import { Generator } from '@asyncapi/generator';

const generator = new Generator('@asyncapi/html-template', './test');
```

I've created my own type definition for the generator as there are no types provided by the library itself.

```js
declare module '@asyncapi/generator' {
  class Generator {
    constructor(templateName: string, targetDir: string, options?: any);
    // more method definitions
  }
}
```

The code seems to compile fine, but at runtime I get the following error:
`TypeError: generator_1.Generator is not a constructor`. When I build my project and inspect the generated javascript code I see what the issue is. The typescript code is compiled as follows.

```js
const generator_1 = require("@asyncapi/generator");
const generator = new generator_1.Generator('@asyncapi/html-template', './test');
```

A [plain javascript example](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator/blob/master/docs/usage.md) that works fine for me shows the difference.

```js
const Generator = require('@asyncapi/generator');
const generator = new Generator('@asyncapi/html-template', './test');
```

I understand why I get the error. The library exports the class definition itself, but I can't figure out how to correctly import it in my typescript code.

```js
class Generator {
  // constructor and method definitions
}

module.exports = Generator;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to:

```js
const Generator = require('@asyncapi/generator');
```

with the ESM import syntax is

```js
import Generator from '@async/generator';
```

this is called a default export.

Your TypeScript definition doesn't match the JavaScript package and this causes
the TypeError.

There are multiple ways to define this type, one way is:

```js
declare module "@asyncapi/generator" {
  export default class Generator {
    constructor(templateName: string, targetDir: string, options?: any);
    // more method definitions
  }
}
```

This requires you to set `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Comment: Wonderful! I can't believe I missed this. Thank you!